# Change and display text in the text box with same button

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            nameTxtBox.Text = employee[i].name;
            addTxtBox.Text = employee[i].address;
            payTxtBox.Text = ($"{employee[i].CalcSalary():c}");
            i++;

        }
```

What I'm trying to do is display the appropriate values for each object in the array of objects `employee` each time I click the Next button. How can I do this?

Comment: Your `i` variable is local to the method and so is reinitialized each time it runs. Make it a class member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost right, but you defined you `i` variable in the wrong scope. It needs to be a field on the class that way its previous value is maintained between each button click.

```
private int i = 0;

private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        nameTxtBox.Text = employee[i].name;
        addTxtBox.Text = employee[i].address;
        payTxtBox.Text = ($"{employee[i].CalcSalary():c}");
        i++;
        // Add logic to make sure 'i' does not go higher than 
        // the total number of items in the array or IndexOutOfBoundException occurs.
}
```